# JAVA: For UPDATE & INSERT, can i use endpoints or GET request to process data in servlet

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, servlets

I have a database with a status of type Tinyint. I would like to change a 0 to a 1 (always) using a link and endpoints like 'notifi?id=&status=1&userid='. Seems it doesnt work without a POST request.

I have tried setting a permanent number for status and tried both update and insert commands but to avail.

HERE is my dao code:

```
public void markRead(Notify notify)  {

    try {
        Connection con= NotifyDao.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(
                "UPDATE notifications set status=? where userid=?");

        ps.setInt(1,notify.getNotifyid());
        ps.setInt(2,notify.getNotifystatus());

        ps.executeUpdate();

        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

My servlet code

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

Notify notify = new Notify();

    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    int status = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("status"));
    int userid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userid"));

    if (status==1){

        request.setAttribute("status", status);

        NotifyDao notifyDao = new NotifyDao();

        notifyDao.markRead(notify);

    }else  {

        response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
    }
```

Any help or direction would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In your servlet override another method `doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)`
along with `doPost()` and call the do post method from there,

like this:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
//your existing code
}  

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
doPost(request,response);
}
```

Also refer [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-)